# Unable to write registry value to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT using c# Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey

Tags: c#

I am working on a Tortoise svn plugin which need to register my program as a COM assembly.
I need to pack registry into a setup program.
Registry value was supposed to wirrten at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID/GUID
But registry value was written to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE totally,and direct to WOW6432NODE.
Here is my code

```
 RegistryKey regHKCR = RegistryKey.ClassesRoot;

 RegistryKey regPlugin = regHKCR.CreateSubKey("ExampleCsPlugin.MyPlugin");
 regPlugin.SetValue("", "ExampleCsPlugin.MyPlugin");

 RegistryKey regCLSID = regHKCR.CreateSubKey("ExampleCsPlugin.MyPlugin\\CLSID");
 regCLSID.SetValue("", "{D765C6EE-477A-4819-9809-BBF1C16F675D}");

 RegistryKey regClsid = regHKCR.CreateSubKey("CLSID\\{D765C6EE-477A-4819-9809-BBF1C16F675D}");
 regClsid.SetValue("", "ExampleCsPlugin.MyPlugin");
 RegistryKey regImplement1 = regClsid.CreateSubKey("Implemented Categories\\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}");
 RegistryKey regImplement2 = regClsid.CreateSubKey("Implemented Categories\\{3494FA92-B139-4730-9591-01135D5E7831}");

 RegistryKey regProgid = regClsid.CreateSubKey("ProgId");
 regProgid.SetValue("", "ExampleCsPlugin.MyPlugin");
 RegistryKey regInproc = regClsid.CreateSubKey("InprocServer32");
 regInproc.SetValue("ThreadingModel", "Both");
 regInproc.SetValue("Class", "ExampleCsPlugin.MyPlugin");
 regInproc.SetValue("Assembly", "ExampleCsPlugin, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
 regInproc.SetValue("RuntimeVersion", "v4.0.30319");
 regInproc.SetValue("CodeBase", "file:///C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xg\\svn_plugin\\ExampleCsPlugin.dll");
 regInproc.SetValue("", "mscoree.dll");
```

I searched on stack,find question about “breaking changes introduced in the framework's registry searching library”.
using

```
RegistryKey regHKCR=RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Registry64)
```

But didn't work.
Then tried MICROSOFT.INSTALLER extension which have a custom install to write registry,but still failed

Comment: What is the bitness of the binary (32 or 64 bit)? `WOW6432NODE` can indicate that your app is running as a 32-bit process, so its registry access is redirected.